# Dynamic delivery user confirmation dialog is shown if the module size is less than 10MB

Tags: android, dynamic-delivery

I have implemented a dynamic module which has a size of 4.6MB and according to google documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore if the size is less than 10MB then we are less likely to get the user confirmation dialog.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue as i do not need the user confirmation for downloading the module if the size is less than 10MB.

Any kind of help would be appreciated[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmOSA.png)